# Create Board Game-like Grid in Python

Tags: python

I am thinking of creating a board game in Python, one which will have a grid of spaces, each with different properties, and which may or may not have pieces resting on them. These pieces should be able to move between spaces, though subject to various rules. (Chess or checkers would be good examples of what I'm thinking of, though my game would have different/more complicated rules, and the grid may not be square, even if the spaces are).

I wrote a Java implementation of something similar for a data structures class, using a modified version of linked lists. But this is Python, so I imagine there's a better way to do it (maybe even a library out there?)

Comment: A Python list is somewhat like a Java linked list.  What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Drawing a chessboard is pretty trivial with Tkinter. Here's a really simple example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
class GameBoard(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, rows=8, columns=8, size=32, color1="white", color2="blue"):
        '''size is the size of a square, in pixels'''

        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.size = size
        self.color1 = color1
        self.color2 = color2
        self.pieces = {}

        canvas_width = columns * size
        canvas_height = rows * size

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                                width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, background="bisque")
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=2, pady=2)

        # this binding will cause a refresh if the user interactively
        # changes the window size
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.refresh)

    def addpiece(self, name, image, row=0, column=0):
        '''Add a piece to the playing board'''
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0, image=image, tags=(name, "piece"), anchor="c")
        self.placepiece(name, row, column)

    def placepiece(self, name, row, column):
        '''Place a piece at the given row/column'''
        self.pieces[name] = (row, column)
        x0 = (column * self.size) + int(self.size/2)
        y0 = (row * self.size) + int(self.size/2)
        self.canvas.coords(name, x0, y0)

    def refresh(self, event):
        '''Redraw the board, possibly in response to window being resized'''
        xsize = int((event.width-1) / self.columns)
        ysize = int((event.height-1) / self.rows)
        self.size = min(xsize, ysize)
        self.canvas.delete("square")
        color = self.color2
        for row in range(self.rows):
            color = self.color1 if color == self.color2 else self.color2
            for col in range(self.columns):
                x1 = (col * self.size)
                y1 = (row * self.size)
                x2 = x1 + self.size
                y2 = y1 + self.size
                self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, outline="black", fill=color, tags="square")
                color = self.color1 if color == self.color2 else self.color2
        for name in self.pieces:
            self.placepiece(name, self.pieces[name][0], self.pieces[name][1])
        self.canvas.tag_raise("piece")
        self.canvas.tag_lower("square")


# image comes from the silk icon set which is under a Creative Commons
# license. For more information see http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/
imagedata = '''
    R0lGODlhEAAQAOeSAKx7Fqx8F61/G62CILCJKriIHM+HALKNMNCIANKKANOMALuRK7WOVLWPV9eR
    ANiSANuXAN2ZAN6aAN+bAOCcAOKeANCjKOShANKnK+imAOyrAN6qSNaxPfCwAOKyJOKyJvKyANW0
    R/S1APW2APW3APa4APe5APm7APm8APq8AO28Ke29LO2/LO2/L+7BM+7BNO6+Re7CMu7BOe7DNPHA
    P+/FOO/FO+jGS+/FQO/GO/DHPOjBdfDIPPDJQPDISPDKQPDKRPDIUPHLQ/HLRerMV/HMR/LNSOvH
    fvLOS/rNP/LPTvLOVe/LdfPRUfPRU/PSU/LPaPPTVPPUVfTUVvLPe/LScPTWWfTXW/TXXPTXX/XY
    Xu/SkvXZYPfVdfXaY/TYcfXaZPXaZvbWfvTYe/XbbvHWl/bdaPbeavvadffea/bebvffbfbdfPvb
    e/fgb/Pam/fgcvfgePTbnfbcl/bfivfjdvfjePbemfjelPXeoPjkePbfmvffnvbfofjlgffjkvfh
    nvjio/nnhvfjovjmlvzlmvrmpvrrmfzpp/zqq/vqr/zssvvvp/vvqfvvuPvvuvvwvfzzwP//////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////yH+FUNyZWF0ZWQgd2l0aCBU
    aGUgR0lNUAAh+QQBCgD/ACwAAAAAEAAQAAAIzAD/CRxIsKDBfydMlBhxcGAKNIkgPTLUpcPBJIUa
    +VEThswfPDQKokB0yE4aMFiiOPnCJ8PAE20Y6VnTQMsUBkWAjKFyQaCJRYLcmOFipYmRHzV89Kkg
    kESkOme8XHmCREiOGC/2TBAowhGcAyGkKBnCwwKAFnciCAShKA4RAhyK9MAQwIMMOQ8EdhBDKMuN
    BQMEFPigAsoRBQM1BGLjRIiOGSxWBCmToCCMOXSW2HCBo8qWDQcvMMkzCNCbHQga/qMgAYIDBQZU
    yxYYEAA7
'''



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    board = GameBoard(root)
    board.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="true", padx=4, pady=4)
    player1 = tk.PhotoImage(data=imagedata)
    board.addpiece("player1", player1, 0,0)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can consider your underlying board implementation as different kind of datastructures.

1. List of lists  - l1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
2. Dict with values as list = d1 = {a:[1,2,3],b:[4,5,6],c:[7,8,9]}
3. Dict with keys are coordinates and values which you can assign.
4. As a [Graph](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs.html)

Here is a design of an empty chessboard.

```
>>> chessboard = {}
>>> for row in range(8):
...     for col in range(8):
...             chessboard[(row,col)] = 0
... 
>>>
```

You can use any of these and design the logic of your game. For higher level elements you can tie these objects or elements within to spites of [pygame](http://www.pygame.org)

Comment: Could you improve your examples to look more like chess boards with rank/file positions?

Comment: @S.Lott - An empty chessboard is a first step perhaps?

Comment: Thanks. Having worked before with lists of lists (and other nested data structures), I'd prefer to use some sort of custom-built structure (especially since I'm going to be adding features. But the Graph and/or Pygame may be a start; I'll check it out.